# How to create a view via hook_update?

Tags: 7, views, hooks, updating

I want to create a view via **hook_update**, looks strange but this is the requirement to bypass allocated memory exhaust error by importing a view.
So if view is created by exporting from local instance and importing in DEV instance am running into a allocated memory exhaust error.

I tried by exporting the view and putting that into the hook_update_N();, but its not created any view. Can anybody guide me how it can be achieved via hook_update?

Comment: You should just increase the **PHP memory limit** specially if you have it on the default 128M, you can check what it is over at `/admin/reports/status`. Try using 256M

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. because of some restrictions in  the server, we cant increase the memory limit. But can you confirm me that its possible via hook_update or not? Because I need to give some justifiable answer to my peers.

Comment: should be possible.

Comment: Thank u buddy.. I got how create it from below link:  https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/examples-for-database-update-scripts-using-hook_update_n-how